# Ambiguity in definition of a henselian ring?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, schemes, hensels-lemma, neron-model

Let $R$ be a local ring, and $S = \operatorname{Spec} R$ be its corresponding scheme. Let $s \in S$ be the closed point. Then Bosch, Lütkebohmert and Raynaud define in *Néron Models*

> **Definition** The local scheme $S$ is called henselian if each étale map $X \to S$ is a local isomorphism at all points $x$ of $X$ over $s$ with trivial residue field extension $k(x) = k(s)$.

I'm not entirely sure about the quantors here: Do we only require $X \to S$ to be a local isomorphism at those points $x \mapsto s$ where $k(x) = k(s)$, or do we require $k(x) = k(s)$ for all $x \mapsto s$?

Comment: Does a *strictly* henselian local ring have any local etale extensions?

Comment: @reuns Possibly, I don't know? By definition $R$ is strictly henselian if it is henselian and $k(s)$ is separably closed.

Comment: Also I favor the first interpretation atm, because if $X \to S$ is a local iso at $x$, then clearly $k(x) = k(s)$, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a silly example: $R= k(s)=: k$.

Then for any Galois extension $L$ of $k$, you get a finite étale map $Spec(L) \to S$ which certainly isn't an isomorphism on the point of $Spec(L)$; but you really want fields to be Henselian (a Henselian ring is one where Hensel's lemma holds : solutions to equations mod $\mathfrak m$ can be lifted to integral solutions, assuming reasonable conditions).

So it must be the first interpretation (it's a local isomorphism at the points for which $k(x) = k(s)$)